# Adicionar elementos a uma lista no pandas

Tags: python, pandas

tenho um dataframe com a seguinte característica:

```
    Incidente   DT_INI  DT_FIM  Status  Descrição
0   IN100   01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
1   IN200   01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
2   IN300   01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_02
3   IN400   01/04/2022  01/05/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_03
4   IN500   01/05/2022  01/06/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_03
```

Estou tentando criar um programa bem simples que baseado em uma lista de valores que será nome de job, no caso : XX_01 e XX_02

esse programa vai buscar no campo "descrição" e cria uma nova lista somente com o filtro de jobs passados e também criar\adicionar uma nova coluna com o nome do jobName.

Eu consegui criar a lista filtrando os jobs passados :

```
list_dados = []
for i in jobName:
    list_dados.append(dados_df_2.loc[dados_df_2['Descrição'].str.contains(i)])

pd.concat(list_dados)
```

Mas, não consegui criar\adicionar a coluna com o nome do job, tentei algumas coisas como adicionar uma nova linha de comando append à lista mas, não consegui.

O output que eu gostaria é :

```
    Incidente   jobName DT_INI  DT_FIM  Status  Descrição
0   IN100   XX_01   01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
1   IN200   XX_01   01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
2   IN300   XX_02   01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_02
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

bom, a resposta para o problema foi usar primeiro o método extract.

```
df['jobName'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'\b(' + '|'.join(jobName) + r'\b)')
```

Depois filtrar os elementos que queria baseado na lista usando a solução que eu já tinha mencionado

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).